# UITextField isn't working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, uitextfield

am new to objective-c programming, so sorry if it's a silly question but i looked thoroughly and couldn't find the error,
p.s: english isn't my first language so programming keywords might be unintentionally used

I've set up a txtfield and defined some of it's properties, such as the keyboard-number pad and stuff, the problem is, when i run it on the simulator, nothing happens, the defult keyboard is called.

i'm just trying to do simple stuff to get it in my head,
in my .h, i have

```
@interface practiceViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *userInput;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) UITextField *userInput;
@end
```

and in my .m

```
-(UITextField *)userInput{
if (userInput == nil) {

userInput=[[UITextField alloc]init];
userInput.keyboardType= UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
userInput.returnKeyType= UIReturnKeyDone;
userInput.textColor=[ UIColor redColor];
userInput.clearButtonMode= UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
userInput.delegate = self;
}

return userInput;
```

}

i also tried to make it as an input, but for some reson it's not working

```
int nInput=[[userInput text] intValue];
```

whats pissing me off about this is that i did the same in a previous project and the "input worked" only,  but now everything isn't.
and my property as i haven't defined anything.
i appreciate your help

Comment: Have you added it as a subview?

Comment: no, am working with a single view only

Comment: Did you add a UITextField object in IB?

Comment: I forgot to do that, thx alot, that's for the input part, but i still have the defult keyboard, and non of the properties are working

Comment: You are creating it programmatically, you don't need to do it in IB again.

Comment: actually if i remove the IB, the nInput would not be assigned a value !

Comment: Did you try using this format instead of dot notation [userInput setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

Answer (score 1):

I Think you have to set the frame for UITextField like this ...

```
userInput.frame=CGRectMake(100,100,60,31);
```

in your -(UITextField *)userInput method, that's y it didn't show ..

Answer (score 0):

Well few things are hazy but ...

You are getting the value of the text field using,

```
int nInput = [[userInput text] intValue];
```

If you are not getting the correct value then `nInput` will be zero. That is because `userInput` must be `nil`. You can verify this by logging it by adding `NSLog(@"%@", userInput);` before the line above.

Whatever value is printed, it looks like your on screen text field is not referenced to by `userInput`.

Since you're doing the entire thing programmatically, you will have to add your `userInput` to the view hierarchy by doing this,

```
[self.view addSubview:self.userInput];
```

Using the property accessor is important here is important as otherwise `userInput` would be `nil` unless you've accessed it using `self.userInput` earlier.

Comment: i might be doing this wrong, it seems that each time i remove my IB, the textfield doesnt react to input, i tried to add it but either didn't knw how or it isn't working, cos it doesn't work,

Comment: thx BTW, but my main problem is that i can't control the proporties of this txtfield, such as the keyboard type, and done button etc, could u figure out the error.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is tagged iPhone, do you happen to be simulating an iPad?  If so, I have run into this.  The iPad will not show a number pad keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 30)]
userInput.keyboardType= UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
userInput.returnKeyType= UIReturnKeyDone;
userInput.textColor=[ UIColor redColor];
userInput.clearButtonMode= UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
userInput.delegate = self;
```

You can just set the frame and add below property(to visible the textfield frame in View otherwise it is not visible in View).

```
  userInput.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
 [self.view addSubview:userInput];
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.